# Use bbox in geoserver sql view

Tags: postgis, geoserver

I'm doing this sql query using geoservers sql views:

```
SELECT kmeans, count(*), ST_BUFFER(ST_CENTROID(ST_Collect(geom)), qrt(count(*))*1000  ) AS geom
FROM (
   SELECT kmeans(ARRAY[ST_X(ST_CENTROID(geom)), ST_Y(ST_CENTROID(geom))], 10) OVER (), geom
      FROM data WHERE foo = %FOO%
)
AS ksub
GROUP BY kmeans
ORDER BY kmeans
```

This always returns the same regardless which bounding box is requestet via the wms. But I want to use the bounding box in my WHERE clause. I know that the user gets a different result then if there are  more tiles used to dislpay a map but that will be ok for me.

Regards

Daniel

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

I found some workaround to this as I was needing to do exactly the same thing, classify using kmeans inside the database depending on the features which are within the extent. I'm using [openlayers](http://openlayers.org).

Here is what I do. In javascript I've put a listener on `precompose` event in the map. Then I can calculate the extents (bbox) inside the javascript and change the request parameters of the `TileWMS` layer.

Here is the piece of code:

```
map.on('precompose', function() {
            var layer = map.getLayers().item(0);
            var view = map.getView();
            var center = view.getCenter();
            var resolution = view.getResolution();
            var size = map.getSize();
            var bbox = [
                center[0] - size[0] * resolution * 0.5,
                center[1] - size[1] * resolution * 0.5,
                center[0] + size[0] * resolution * 0.5,
                center[1] + size[1] * resolution * 0.5
            ];
            layer.getSource().params_.x1 = bbox[0];
            layer.getSource().params_.y1 = bbox[1];
            layer.getSource().params_.x2 = bbox[2];
            layer.getSource().params_.y2 = bbox[3];
        });
```

Everytime the map is going to compose it updates the `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2` parameters, so I can use them in my SQL View.